# Can I preserve placeholder if the user select the input text, and the input value is empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, placeholder

The input can set the placeholder, but if the user focus on that input , the place holder is disappear, how can I dismiss the placeholder, util the user start type at less one char?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the default behavior. However, You could it do by adding some JS into the mix

Live fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/gPBhX/

```
<input type='text' class='placeholder' data-title='hello'>

$('.placeholder').each(function(){
    $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('data-title'));
    $(this).val($(this).attr('data-title'));
});

$('.placeholder').live('keydown', function(){
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('placeholder')) {
        $(this).val('');         
    } 
});

$('.placeholder').live('blur', function(){
    if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
        $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder'));
    }
});
```

Note : There's a limitation where if a user pastes some text into the box it won't clear, but you could easily fix that by binding to the change event as well. This is just a demo

Answer (score 0):

Using the `placeholder` attribute, you can't.